# SSH Targets , How to "Connect to Host in New Tab"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am learning how to use SSH Targets in VS code on my Mac to check/edit the files in remote server.
The annoying part is I am unable to connect to the remote host in a new tab. It gives me only below options:

Connect to Host in New Window
Connect to Host in Current Window

When i choose the Current Windows all my open local files are forced to quit.

Anybody can suggest how to workaround this problem in vs code itself?